# How to upload image in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is my form

```
@extends('layout.template')
    @section('content')
        <h1>Add Student</h1>
        {!! Form::open(array('action' => 'studentController@save', 'files'=>true)) !!}

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Profile-Picture', 'Profile Picture:') !!}
            {!! Form::file('image',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::submit('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    @stop
```

This is my controller method

```
public function save()
{
    $students=Request::all();
    students::create($students);
    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Record successfully added!');
    return redirect('students');
}
```

when i upload image and submit image than in the database column field save this image address "/tmp/phpFFuMwC";

Answer (score 0):

That' s because you are saving the temporarily generated file url.

For files you need to manually save it to the desired location
( make sure it passes validations ):

```
$request->file('photo')->move($destinationPath);

// With a custom filename    
$request->file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
```

and then store the new filename ( with or without the path ) in the database something like this:

```
$students = new Students;
$students->image = $fileName;
...
$students->save();
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#files

Comment: PS: You should probably use `Session::put` and `Session::get` methods instead of `Session::flash`.

Answer (score 0):

On your controlller make these changes

```
public function save(Request $request)
{
    $destination = 'uploads/photos/'; // your upload folder
    $image       = $request->file('image');
    $filename    = $image->getClientOriginalName(); // get the filename
    $image->move($destination, $filename); // move file to destination

    // create a record
    Student::create([
        'image' => $destination . $filename
    ]);

    return back()->withSuccess('Success.');
}
```

Don't forget to use

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```